# Prestashop 1.7 file saving

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

How to upload a file and save it in Prestashop 1.7?

In **ProductComments** module I have a modal with a `<form>`:

*post-comment-modal.tpl*

```
<form id="post-product-comment-form" action="{$post_comment_url nofilter}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input name="comment_title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"/>
      <label for="comment_title">Title</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input name="customer_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
      <label for="customer_name">Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <textarea name="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Review"></textarea>
      <label for="comment_content">Review</label>
    </div>

    <input type="file" id="photo_input" name="photo_input" multiple> // I've added this field

    <button type="submit">Send</button>

  </div>

</form>
```

I've added there a `<input type="file">`.

This form is posted into ProductCommentsPostCommentModuleFrontController which extends ModuleFrontController

*PostComment.php*

```
class ProductCommentsPostCommentModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function display()
    {

        $id_product = (int) Tools::getValue('id_product');
        $comment_title = Tools::getValue('comment_title');        // Proper value
        $comment_content = Tools::getValue('comment_content');    // Proper value
        $customer_name = Tools::getValue('customer_name');        // Proper value
        $criterions = (array) Tools::getValue('criterion');
        $photo = Tools::getValue('photo_input');                  // false
        $file = $_FILES['photo_input']['name'];                   // null

        // Validation

        /** @var EntityManagerInterface $entityManager */
        $entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        //Create product comment
        $productComment = new ProductComment();

        // Validation

        $productComment
            ->setProductId($id_product)
            ->setTitle($comment_title)
            ->setContent($comment_content)
            ->setCustomerName($customer_name)
            ->setCustomerId($this->context->cookie->id_customer)
            ->setGuestId($this->context->cookie->id_guest)
            ->setDateAdd(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')))
        ;


        $entityManager->persist($productComment);
        $this->addCommentGrades($productComment, $criterions);

        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->ajaxRender(
            json_encode(
                [
                    'success' => true,
                    'product_comment' => $productComment->toArray(),
                ]
            )
        );
    }
```

Is there a way to extend this controller, and add a variable which holds a file upoaded by user by POST method?

Comment: What is your primary question; extending a controller, processing an image from a form, saving the image in file system or all of the aforementioned?

Comment: Good point, I want to know how to process an image from a form just for now

Comment: Are you posting the form data through ajax? it could be the reason for returning the null value in photo_input.

Comment: Checkout this basic tutorial on handling image update: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. Also make sure you check the file extension by using `pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` check if that is in a list of allowed extension, like jpeg, png, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm posting it through ajax